# Can a validation weed out bad data, but still let the rest of a form to continue through creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

When a form of data is submitted to creation, can the validations just weed out the bad data and not create those instances, but allow the other "good data" continue through?

So for a more clear scenario, say I am submitting a form that is creating a new Book, but on this form there are 10 fields to create 10 different Books at once. I have a validation on Book that says presence is true. When the user fills in the form lets say they just have 8 of the 10 book slots filled out. Since the last 2 empty Book slots are blank, the validation will work to stop that creation, but I still want the rest of the data to go through with being created.

I'm new to coding so I was really struggling to find the right words so I could find a clear answer via Google. Thank you for the help!

EDIT: My actual project is using a Card model:

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :group

    validates :front,:back, presence: true
end
```

Form:

```
    <h3>Cards</h3>
    <%= f.fields_for :cards do |c| %>
        <%= c.label :front %>
        <%= c.text_field :front %>

        <%= c.label :back %>
        <%= c.text_field :back %>
        <br />
    <% end %>
```

Its a nested form so this is the new, create and strong params in my Group controller:

```
    def new
        if params[:user_id] && @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
            @group = @user.groups.build
            @group.build_category
            5.times {@group.cards.build}
        else
            @group = Group.new
        end
    end

    def create
        @group = current_user.groups.build(group_params)

        if @group.save
            redirect_to user_groups_path(current_user)
        else
            redirect_to new_user_group_path(current_user)
        end
    end

    private

        def group_params
            params.require(:group).permit(:title, :description, :category_id, category_attributes: [:name], 
                cards_attributes: [:front, :back])
        end
```

Error: There is no error output its just rerendering the new form page and highlighting the 'field_with_error' in red. Like its expecting all fields to be complete.

Comment: Interesting I'm getting a different result. When the user doesn't fill in all book fields, it re renders the form and doesn't go through. I'm going to include my validations and form to the question.

Comment: Ok, do you have multiple occurrences of that card form on the view or just the one?  If it is just the one then that is the expected result, if there are more than that you will need to handle the validation of that to account for that.  Also can you include (in the question) the exact error output you are getting? I feel that will provide the most insight into what is going on.

Comment: Yes, it is multiple text fields! Okay I'm going to add in more info to the post.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense! Okay yeah I think trying to remove the validations and creating the before_save method should be a good next step. Do you think its also possible to maybe create a custom card_attributes=(attributes) setter method? Like maybe inside the setter method I can tell it to go through each one, if blank then skip? (is 'skip' a thing that can happen in ruby?'), and then save the ones that have a present? result. And yes the point of the validation is that I dont want the groups to have any cards that are just blank sitting in there.

Comment: I think the answer below is what you are looking for probably.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation is ok and necessary to avoid saving records with missing fields, so keep it.

The cleanest way to achieve what you're looking for, is to set `accepts_nested_attributes_for :cards, reject_if: :all_blank` on your `Group` model. The `:all_blank` will reject records which have all their attributes blank. Also you can set your own criteria for rejecting records like follows:

```rb
class Group  < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :cards
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :cards, reject_if: :card_is_empty?

   private
   def card_is_empty?(c)
      c.front.blank? && c.back.blank?
   end
end
```

An other way is to put a `before_validation :remove_empty_cards` on your `Group` model and in `remove_empty_cards` method remove all cards that have empty front and back.

Comment: Thank you so much this is very helpful!